# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []

Tags: java, ssl, https, rest-assured

When I try to Hit the URL using Postman it works fine,by using my personal cert.But when I tried the same using Rest Assured test case it is throwing the above exception.

Configuration Class

```
public class Configuration {

    protected SSLConfig config = null;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Configuration.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @BeforeClass
    public void setKeystore()

    {
        KeyStore keyStore = null;

        KeyStore trustStore = null;
        try {
            String certPassword = System.getProperty("certPassword");
            String certPath = System.getProperty("certPath");

            String trustStorePassword = System.getProperty("trustStorePassword");
            String trustStorePath = System.getProperty("trustStorePath");
            Validate.notNull(certPath, "Path to Certificate on the file system cannot be null");
            Validate.notEmpty(certPassword, "Password cannot be empty");
            Validate.notNull(trustStorePath, "Path to trustStore on the file system cannot be null");
            Validate.notEmpty(trustStorePassword, "TrustStore Password cannot be empty");

            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(certPath), certPassword.toCharArray());
            trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStorePath), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());

            if (keyStore != null) {

                org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory clientAuthFactory = new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory(
                        keyStore, certPassword, trustStore);
                config = new SSLConfig().with().sslSocketFactory(clientAuthFactory).and().allowAllHostnames();

            }
            EnvironmentConstants.getEnvironment();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error while loading keystore");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public Properties loadproperties() {

        InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("errorMessages.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return properties;
    }

}
```

Comment: We can't help without looking at your code.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes see below my answer.

Comment: But why it works with POSTMan?

Comment: Postman and soapUI has the capability to Bypass this DNS issue, where as in Java your writing your own code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928061/certificate-for-localhost-doesnt-match-any-of-the-subject-alternative-names)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is because of,our company configured new servers ,but did not included DNS in server cert.So my company include server names in cert.Now it is working.

Answer (score 4):

According to [RFC 2818 (the HTTPS specification)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> If the hostname is available, the client MUST check it against the
> server's identity as presented in the server's Certificate message,
> in order to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks...
> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
> be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
> field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is **deprecated** and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.

You should generate certificate with SAN extension containing all hostnames where you're planning to use the certificate:

```
keytool -genkeypair \
    -keystore server-keystore.pkcs12 \
    -deststoretype pkcs12 \
    -dname "CN=mydomain.local" \
    -keypass changeit \
    -storepass changeit \
    -keyalg RSA \
    -validity 1825 \
    -keysize 4096 \
    -alias mydomain.local \
    -ext SAN=dns:mydomain.local,dns:mydomain.dev,dns:mydomain.test,dns:localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make successful request with REST Assured, you can try use method `.allowAllHostnames()` for `SSLConfig`.

That way client won't verify hostname.