# Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate

**The Error**:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [xxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxx.xxx]
```

I have a Spring Boot App running in my `localhost`. I also have a tunnel `ssh` via putty to a server.

Things I have done:

- I manually created/imported keys/certificates of all ways.
- I used -ext from keytool to add the dns addr and the localhost to SAN.
- I also used a    [openSource](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) java file to install the cert.
- I changed the hosts    files to: 127.0.0.1 xxx.xxx.xxxxxxx.xxx (if I ping the dns name it responds to the localhost address)
- I used the VM Arguments -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to check if the certs are loading properly.

What am I missing? BTW, I'm also using a VPN.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to provide localhost as a subject alternative name when creating your certificate. You can do that by provide the following additional parameter: `-ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1"`

So something like this:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias stackoverflow \
-dname "CN=stackoverflow,OU=Hakan,O=Hakan,C=NL" \
-ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -validity 3650 \
-storepass <password> -keypass <password> \
-keystore identity.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

**Some explanation:**

The SAN field will be used to match the hostname, which will be provided in the request. So when you are running your application on localhost, lets say `https://localhost:443`, and you also want to make a request to that specific host, then that hostname should also be available within the SAN field; otherwise, it will fail during the handshake process.

Let's grab Stackoverflow as an example. To be able to reach stackoverflow over https we would expect that the certificate should contain at least an entry of `stackoverflow.com`

Below is the certificate SAN value of stackoverflow with the specific DNS highlighted for this example:
[image: Stackoverflow certificate san values]

As you can see already it contains also other DNS values. In this way websites owners can use the same certificate for multiple websites/subdomains etc.

Comment: why alternative names contains itself stackoverflow.com?

Comment: what do you mean by it contains itself?